# Checkout Onepage Item.phtml doesnt care about changes

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

im trying to edit the Onepage Checkout Item view for hours now.
After many ways of trying I´ve found out that especially this one file seems to be loaded from somewhere else.

Loaded files: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/
button.phtml, info.phtml, totals.phtml, -item.phtml-> changes doesnt appear.
If I change something in each single file its displayed so it should be loaded or used at this point.

If I change the item.phtml nothing happens so there should be another "item.phtml" file somewhere else. I´ve already searched the whole directory of the shop - no item.phtml found (just this one).

Im getting crazy... Someone got a solution or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable template path hints and you will see where the file is located.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

Go to `System -> Configuration` in the main menu

Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

Remember to clear your cache.

Source [here.](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-)

Comment: Thats it, thanks very much! I didnt know this function...